# How to fix these issues with Nylon?

Tags: ultimaker-cura, nylon, dremel-3d45

I'm using Ultimaker Cura and a Dremel 3D45S with an eSun Nylon filament.
As starting point I'm using the default settings of the printer, 260 °C for the hotend and 80 °C for the bed.

These are the results:

[image]
[image]
[image]

In addition to the poor print quality, the resulting dimensions are wrong. For example, the cylinder is supposed to have a wall thickness of 5 mm, with an inner diameter of 35 mm and the outer diameter of 45 mm. With ABS they are quite good (just a 0.2 mm difference). With nylon they are off by 1 mm! The wall has a thickness of 6 mm.

For both materials the flow is set to 100 %

Any ideas on what I should change to improve the printing?

Here my current settings for Nylon:

[image]

Comment: Looks like slight over extrution, and also use the newer slicer engine for better Z seam alignment, going a little slower may also help with this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look up the [hardness](https://plasticranger.com/what-is-shore-hardness-scale/) of Nylon with respect to ABS you will find that ABS is generally much harder. The effect of softer filament is that the teeth of the extruder feeder dig in more into the filament (so for every rotation of the gear, less material is extruded than in hard filament), if you do not correct for this (lower the extrusion flow modifier) you are under-extruding material.

This is clearly not happening in your case!

The effects you see are caused by over-extrusion. This can cause the effects you see on the outside of your print and also result in dimensional inaccuracies. You need to tune the printer for different materials. Try to extrude 100 mm of filament and see how much is being extruded (mark some filament from a reference point and redo the measurement after extrusion).

Also make sure the filament is dry, Nylon tends to take up moisture which can bubbling (boiling the moisture) during extrusion.

Comment: While there appears to be other issues.  The first thought I had looking at the print is a problem with moisture.